# How to add newline while using everyline in mdframed?

Tags: formatting, mdframed

I am working on `mdframed` and found solution of using `mdframed` on multiple pages by using everyline but it new box has no margin or newline. So it starts from beginning which looks odd?

```
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1,
linecolor=maincol,outerlinewidth=.5, innerleftmargin=8,
innertopmargin=8,innerbottommargin=8, everyline = true]
```

[image]

How can i add margin or newline to it?

Regards

Comment: See documentation

Comment: I have read documentation but could not find the way of writing newline for splitted frames.

Comment: See: `splittopskip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the package doesn't draw lines at the bottom or top of splitted frames. You can change this settings by the option `everyline=true`

To influence the space at the top of a splitted frame use the option `splittopskip`. For further details please have a look at the documentation.